# Strange program bug after export project from eclipse-adt to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

1. There is N old projects for API 13-14, on eclipse(juno)+adt. All projects are compiling, working, etc.
2. After import (one of) them into Android Studio, its also good compiling, but...
3. Using of startActivityForResult immediatelty destroys parent(main) activity, if dev flag *do not store* is on. If flag is off, all working good. Is normal, but...
4. original eclipse project is working good (not destroys parent immediately) in all states of dev flag.

I think there is a difference of defaut processing in each case or may be something expected in manifest?
It may be because the parent has openGl context, but eclipse project works good...
The parent activity gets too many different data (used to monitoring a real time signal) and destroing it is very bad for me.

There is only one question - why this fatal difference is, and how to avoid this?
Reload state manually in (onSaveState) is too complex and not correct.